# Friends lists -- keeping track of users

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is there a better way of keeping track of users you want to follow than just visiting their page manually every time?   I've found I enjoy looking at various users' posts and the list of usernames/names to remember is reaching the limits of my memory.

I am not a twitter user or anything but I can see why you may want to have a 'follow' feature and then a 'friends' tab to view their activity.

Comment: Should this be a feature-request?

Comment: Ah, here's the respective request on main meta: [A “friends list” on Stack Overflow would be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/886/146482)

Comment: ...and a StackApp names [FriendOverflow](http://stackapps.com/questions/1863/follow-your-friends-on-stackoverflow-with-friendoverflow)

Comment: Thanks Tobias, FriendOverflow seems like the type of thing I was interested in.  I'll attempt to install it.

Comment: I found a second StackApp that attempts something similar called Favorite Users http://stackapps.com/questions/3535/stack-exchange-favorite-users I'm not sure if Mike Grace is still supporting the very nice FriendOverflow.  He might be, of course. I was merely reading the comments though, which made me uncertain. I don't know about the usefulness of the other StackApp, merely that the creation date was 2012 and Mike's was 2010.

Comment: @FeralOink Good point. [This comment](http://stackapps.com/questions/1863/follow-your-friends-on-stackoverflow-with-friendoverflow#comment7503_1863) "The "follow" button probably isn't showing up on user's profiles because the markup of the page has probably changed. The app will need to be updated to work with the new markup or changed to not rely on page markup." suggests FriendOverflow is outdated indeed. Though the favorite users app you linked seems to only highlight actual posts - which in combination with the user feed might actually work very nice

Comment: I love math!! OK. Now that we have that small detail out of the way, lets get on to the real business. It's great to see ya'll talking about my app that I started a few years ago but sad to realize that I have failed to update my app in years. Guess it's still a good idea to get it updated and working again. If I were to resurrect my FriendOverflow project, it would probably start as a native Google Chrome extension. I also like the discussion happening on meta about the "friend list". What do ya'll think? Thanks @FeralOink for letting me know about this conversation :)

Comment: Hi @MikeGrace! I'm happy that the invocation worked, and brought you here. Are you referring to the same discussion about "friends list" as Tobias mentioned in his comment of 21 Mar at 16:23? I use and like Google Chrome web browser. My only concern would be that it not cause lag. Some Chrome extensions do, even a few made by Google. That's merely an aside. Also, I don't know if there's devotion to Safari or IE. muzzlator might want to chime in.

Comment: I am referring to the same discussion about "friends list" that Tobias mentioned in his comment. I hate lag also so the extension would be built to reduce lag as much as possible. Everything would be loaded locally so the only thing that would cause lag would be calling the stackexchange API to look up your "friends" activity. The extension could be setup to do this automatically while on a stackexchange site or only on demand. I would like to build it as a native Chrome extension instead of a Kynetx app to reduce lag issues. This would prevent me from developing a Safari or IE version though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Scroll to the bottom of the user profile and check the link [user feed](https://math.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/60855) to obtain an RSS feed.

Comment: Maybe it is worth pointing out that the user feed also contains comments. Some possibilities how to restrict to answers or questions are mentioned here: [Answer Only RSS feed for a user](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14183).

Comment: At least on mobile, as of the date of this answer, you have to switch to the 'Activity' tab of the Profile page. (In case anyone else finds the site design as non-obvious as i do.)

Answer (score 7):

I was pondering the same question recently, and tried the user RSS feed, but found it too noisy/stalkish. I don't need to read every comment left by the user, especially since comments show up without context. What I wanted was the list of recent, unanswered questions posted by    "whitelisted" users: those whom I identified as reliable posters of decent   questions in areas of interest to me.

An initial approximation to the  list of users was obtained with the query [Users whose questions you have answered](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/154133/users-whose-questions-you-have-answered). It's an interesting query to run even if you don't plan on using the filter described below.

For the filtering purpose I used [StackExchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) . For example,

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users/12345;76543/questions/unanswered?pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=activity&site=math
```

gives the list of up to 100 (the `pagesize` parameter)  unanswered (in the SE sense) questions asked by the specified users (Id numbers 12345 and 76543), sorted by last activity. One can also narrow down the search by replacing `unanswered` with `no-answers`, or expand it by dropping `unanswered` altogether. The list of users can have up to 100 semicolon-separated Id numbers.

Being an interface for *applications*, API returns the list in the JSON format, which is pretty clean, but not exactly an eye candy:

```
{"items":[{"tags":["laplace-transform"],"owner":{"display_name":"MacArthur Nguyen","link":"http://math.stackexchange.com/users/76543/macarthur-nguyen","profile_image":"https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb3po.jpg?s=128&g=1","accept_rate":0,"user_type":"registered","user_id":76543,"reputation":68},"title":"Find the Laplace transform:$f(t) = \\int_0^t {{e^{it}}\\frac{{dt}}{{\\sqrt {2\\pi t} }}}$","link":"http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388606/find-the-laplace-transformft-int-0t-eit-fracdt-sqrt-2-pi-t","question_id":388606,"last_edit_date":1368288098,"creation_date":1368288056,"last_activity_date":1368316174,"score":0,"answer_count":1,"view_count":85,"is_answered":false},
```

But having installed the Chrome extension *JSON Formatter*, I found JSON output almost as   readable as SE  pages. The long lines with green text are all I need to read, and the `link` field is clickable.

[image: formatted JSON]

Of course, the proper way to use this functionality would be to write a script that inserts the data into an actual HTML page.

Answer (score 6):

I can recommend [StackEye](https://stackapps.com/questions/4454/stackeye-chrome-extension-to-follow-users-and-questions-on-stackexchange-sites), a Chrome extension that allows one to follow SE users (as well as particular questions). It adds a Follow button to each user's profile:

[image: t.b.]

The notifications on the extension icon are an unobtrusive number (not some flashy-red thing). Upon a click, you get a list like this:

[image]

Although not see on the screenshot, questions asked by followed users are also included in notifications.

Comment: Sir I tried StackEye but this was not working. I used it in chromium. The follow button was not visible on the profile page of the user. The eye symbol was available on the question page to watch or unwatch the question. This was working fine. If I watched a question by clicking the eye symbol then that question was available in the watch list. 
Kindly see that is this the problem of site or the problem of browser. 
The follow button is not visible. Thank you.