# Is there a way to follow users?

Tags: feature-request

There are a lot of interesting people here on MSE. I wanted to know if there is a way to follow (get notified) if a user is posting comments, questions and answers?

I just want to follow them because they are contributing really cool stuff and I think I can learn a lot from them.

Visiting the corresponding profiles is not a feasible method.

Comment: See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8845/11619). I don't think any related changes to site SW have been added since.

Comment: Thank you. So there is no option without extensions.

Comment: I'm rather curious; if you are so motivated to follow a user, you can visit their profile to keep up with new posts. Why do you say: "Visiting the corresponding profiles is not a feasible method."  Because that's what you have to work with.  Any way, it gets a tad spooky, and weird, because someone wanting to stalk a user could ask the very same question post as you used here.

Comment: @amWhy The reason why I said that it is not feasible is that there are multiple users +15 that I want to follow. Remembering usernames and visiting the profiles is just not feasible. They really contribute great stuff, that is why I want to follow them. If I would like to stalk one user it would be a feasible method to visit the profile :D.

Comment: **Step 1**: Join one of the intelligence/homeland security-related agencies of your country of origin. **Step 2:** Work your way up the chain until you're a fairly high ranking official there. **Step 3:** Abuse your power and request the IT guys to write a program that follows users on StackExchange (if they don't have one already), and use that to follow whomever you wanted to follow.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Very funny but not constructive. The featuring of following users is not something that I invented.

Comment: This is not a social website. This is not Facebook, MySpace, DeviantArt, or even Quora. This site is a Q&A site. The day social features are introduced is the day I am starting to look for another place to spend my time online.

Comment: @AsafKatagila: I don’t want to argue about the nature of MSE. I just asked if there is such a feature.